# Access to core comment preprocess variables in a custom comment layout twig template?

Tags: 8, comments, theming

In Drupal 8 I have a custom comment type and when I use the default core comment.html.twig to render the comments then variables like 'new_indicator_timestamp' and 'parent' get rendered as expected. But if I switch to using a custom layout (via layout_plugin and display suite) and copy across the relevant twig template code for those core comment preprocess variables into my own custom layout then they don't work.

What do I need to do to ensure that the comment.module `template_preprocess_comment()` variables are available to my custom comment layout?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the twig changed, layout modules usually bring their own templates. You have to check which templates are used. To find this out use twig debug:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374

After you found the right twig you have to use the corresponding preprocess hook, which you find in the comments of the twig template.

Comment: I already have twig debugging turned on and have confirmed that the custom twig template I created is the one that's being used, so that's not the issue here.

D8 core comments template variables are defined in  comment.module template_preprocess_comment(). The issue is that these **core** variables aren't available in my custom template when applied to comments and I don't understand why.

Surely if these variables are defined in the core module file (rather than a specific theme) then they should be available to **any** template that is used for comments?

Comment: No, the variables are only available in **one** template. See the second part of my answer.